# Combine multiple lsof options

Tags: lsof

Is there any way to combine the `-i` and `-p` options of `lsof` in a logical conjunction? It seems to me that the default behavior is to show files which satisfy one or the other condition, which I think is a bit odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-a` option as shown in one of the [examples in the `lsof` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html#EXAMPLES):

```
To list all open IPv4 network files in use by the process whose
PID is 1234, use:

       lsof -i 4 -a -p 1234
```

The [“Options” section](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html#OPTIONS) explains:

```
Normally list options that are specifically stated are ORed -
i.e., specifying the -i option without an address and the -ufoo
option produces a listing of all network files OR files belonging
to processes owned by user ``foo''.  The exceptions are:

[…]

The -a option may be used to AND the selections.  For example,
specifying -a, -U, and -ufoo produces a listing of only UNIX
socket files that belong to processes owned by user ``foo''.

Caution: the -a option causes all list selection options to be
ANDed; it can't be used to cause ANDing of selected pairs of
selection options by placing it between them, even though its
placement there is acceptable.  Wherever -a is placed, it causes
the ANDing of all selection options.

Items of the same selection set - command names, file
descriptors, network addresses, process identifiers, user
identifiers, zone names, security contexts - are joined in a
single ORed set and applied before the result participates in
ANDing.  Thus, for example, specifying -i@aaa.bbb, -i@ccc.ddd,
-a, and -ufff,ggg will select the listing of files that belong to
either login ``fff'' OR ``ggg'' AND have network connections to
either host aaa.bbb OR ccc.ddd.

[…]

-a     causes list selection options to be ANDed, as described
       above.
```